# Showing that $\mathcal{V}(f,g) \subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^n$ has three irreducible components.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, maximal-and-prime-ideals, affine-varieties

I was working on this following exercise and i would really like to see if i understood things correctly.

> Let $V:=\mathcal{V}(X^2-YZ,XZ-X) \subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^n$. Show that $V$ has
> three irreducible components and find the corresponding prime ideals.

---

**What i know:** I know that any subvariety $V$ of the affine space $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ is a noetherian topological space (with respect to the subspace topology of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$). Now the irreducible components are the maximal irreducible closed subsets of a topological space.

The irreducible components of $V$ correspond to the minimal prime ideals of the coordinate ring $$A(V) = k[X,Y,Z]/{\mathcal{I}(V)}$$ where $\mathcal{I}(V)$ is the Ideal of $V$.

---

However, the proposed solution to this exercise considers the minimal prime ideals of $k[X,Y,Z]$, which is however the coordinate ring of the affine space $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ and rather than the coordinate ring of $V$.

So I'm guessing, that we are actually looking for the irreducible components of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ rather than $V$?

What am i missing? Please be aware that I'm new to algebraic geometry and have yet to learn the connections.

**My question:** Are we supposed to find the minimal prime ideals of the coordinate ring $A(V) = k[X,Y,Z]/{\mathcal{I}(V)}$ or is it actually $A(\mathbb{A}_k^n) = k[X,Y,Z]$ ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What are $f, g$?

Comment: Oh, i'm really sorry, fixing that in a second.

Comment: If $k$ denotes a field, then the only minimal prime of $R := k[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}]$ is $(0)$, since $R$ is a domain. (Indeed, affine space over a field is irreducible precisely for this reason.) You are correct that want to compute the minimal prime ideals of $A(V)$, not $R$. I haven't seen the solution that you reference, but it's possible that what is actually discussed is how to compute the minimal primes of $R$ lying *over* the ideal generated by $X^2-YZ, XZ-X$. If this is the case, then do you see why this is the same as computing the minimal primes of $A(V)$?

Comment: Thank you @AlexWertheim. I think it slowly starts to make sense (i hope). The solution says that any irreducible component $V'\subseteq V$ is an irreducible closed subset of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ and therefore corresponds to a primeideal $\frak p$ of $k[X,Y,Z]$. Since $V'$ is maximal as an irreducible closed subset of $V$, the respective prime ideal is minimal over the ideal $\sqrt{(X^2-YZ, XZ-X)}$. 

Since the prime ideals over $\sqrt{(X^2-YZ, XZ-X)}$ coincide with the prime ideals over $(X^2-YZ, XZ-X)$, it suffices to demand that $\frak p$ is minimal over $(X^2-YZ, XZ-X)$.

Comment: So i think the key observation here is that irreducible components of $V$ are irreducible closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$, thus they correspond to prime ideals ${\frak p}\subseteq k[X,Y,Z]$.

As maximal subsets of $V$, i am interested in the minimal prime ideals over $(X^2-YZ, XZ-X)$ (using that the primes over $\sqrt{\frak a}$ coincide with the primes over $\frak a$ apparently).

Would that be a reasonable point of view?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Since you seem unsure about it, I might add that the the primes over $\sqrt{I}$ coincide with the primes over $I$ because prime ideals are radical: that is, for any prime ideal $P$, $\sqrt{P} = P$, and so if $P$ contains $I$, then taking radicals gives $P = \sqrt{P}$ contains $\sqrt{I}$. (Conversly, since $\sqrt{I}$ contains $I$, any prime which contains $\sqrt{I}$ necessarily contains $I$.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Alex, you were truly helpful. Also thanks for the additional remark regarding the primes. Feel free to copy any of your comments as an answer if you like, i'd happily accept it.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I'm happy to convert my comments to an answer if I have the time later. However, your comments indicate a good understanding of the situation, and I would encourage you to answer your own question. Explaining how you resolved your confusion will surely help future readers in your same situation, and is a good exercise in solidifying your own understanding. (I will gladly upvote such an answer, provided it does not contain errors, of course.)

Comment: I'll happily do so, thanks for the suggestion. I'm really happy i'm starting to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @AlexWertheim I managed to understand where my confusion was coming from.

An irreducible component $V'$ of $V:=\mathcal{V}(X^2−YZ,XZ−X)\subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^3$ is an irreducible closed subsets of the affine space $\mathbb{A}_k^3$.

Throughout, let ${\frak a}:= (X^2−YZ,XZ−X)$.

Since $V'\subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^3$ is irreducible if and only if its ideal $\mathcal{I}(V') \subseteq k[X,Y,Z]$ is prime, we know that $\mathcal{I}(V')$ must be a prime ideal in $k[X,Y,Z]$.

The irreducible component $V'$ of the affine variety $V$ is a *maximal* irreducible closed subset of $V$. Therefore, the prime ideal $\frak p$ must be minimal over the ideal of $V =\mathcal{V}({\frak a})$.

The ideal of $\mathcal{V}({\frak a})$ is given by $$\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}({\frak a})) = \sqrt{{\frak a}}$$

Note that ${\frak a}\subseteq \sqrt{{\frak a}}$ and $\sqrt{{\frak p}} = {\frak p}$ since prime ideals are radical ideals, it holds that the prime ideals over $\sqrt{a}$ coincide with the prime ideals over $\frak a$ (see comments),  thus it suffices to compute the minimal prime ideals over $\frak a$. Those minimal primes then correspond to the irreducible components of $V$.

**In Summary:** irreducible components of an affine variety $V\subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^n$ are in particular irreducible closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ and thus correspond to prime ideals in $k[X_1,...,X_n]$. The irreducible components of $V$ being *maximal* irreducible closed subsets of $V$ then correspond to the *minimal* primes in $k[X_1,...,X_n]$ over the ideal $\mathcal{I}(V)$ of $V$.